# Multi-semicolon Line Endings: Acceptable?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, syntax, line-endings

So, while I was working on some code for my next app update, I noticed something strange:  You can put a very large amount of semicolons at the end of Objective-C statements and it will compile just fine!  Heck, it runs the same as well.  Why in the world does this work?

Comment: Each semicolon terminates a statement. You can have as many statements on a line as you wish. Why *shouldn't* this work?

Comment: Prohibiting this would make it very hard to create an empty statement for cases where the grammar of the language requires one and you happen to not want to do anything.

Comment: I always thought semicolons worked like periods in a sentence (you only need one, and any more would do something strange).

Comment: Completely unacceptable. You'll be wasting an extra byte on every line!

Comment: There is no such thing as "near infinite". You're either infinite or as far away from it as zero is :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Check the edit, I assume you'll be content now that all of the mathematical paradoxes of the world have been grammar nazi'd out of existence (LOL).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Not really; I don't think there are any situations where `{}` would not suffice for an empty statement or block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Semicolons are just used to end the current statement. Empty statements are permitted in C-like languages, for example:

```
int len = 0;
while(str[len++]); // count the length of a null-terminated string
```

```
if (1) {} else { printf("Uh oh... this can't be happening!\n"); }
```

They don't do anything.

Placing an arbitrarily large number of semicolons at the end of the line is just an extreme case of this.

Answer (score 5):

Each extra semicolon represents a statement which does nothing.

Also, simple expressions like `0;` are legal code which do nothing.